# every datatable row iteration is slower than the previous one

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datatables

I'm using vb.net (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2) with SQLite.
I've a table with 52000 rows and I have to iterate each of them with the purpose of creating a csv file.
That's my code, very simple.

```
    Dim text As String
    Dim dtRows As Integer
    Dim dtColumns As Integer

    text = ""
    dtRows = dt.Rows.Count - 1
    dtColumns = dt.Columns.Count - 1

    'set column header'

    For y As Integer = 0 To dtColumns
        text &= dt.Columns.Item(y).ColumnName.ToString
        If (y <> dtColumns) Then
            text &= ";"
        End If
    Next
    textOnlyColumn = text
    text &= vbCrLf

    For x As Integer = 0 To dtRows
        'set row values'
        For y As Integer = 0 To dtColumns
            text &= dt(x)(y)
            If (y <> dtColumns) Then
                text &= ";"
            Else
                text &= vbCrLf
            End If
        Next

        If (x Mod 300 = 0 And x <> 0) Then
            WriteIntoFile(fileName, text)
            text = textOnlyColumn

            ts = Now().Subtract(t1)
            addText(TextLog, "Execution time in " + ts.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + " msec.")
            t1 = Now()

            Application.DoEvents()
        End If
    Next

    WriteIntoFile(fileName, text)
```

The problem is: **every iteration is slower than the previous one**. every 300 rows, the time grows about 50 msec (as you can see in this photo).

[Echo every 300 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL5Cx.png)

Why?
The memory in the diagnostic session **don't grow**.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so since you are concatenating the current string has to be recreated 300 times in the loop which is slow.  There are several faster ways from using a collection, but why cache them at all?  Write each line to a stream as you format it.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: On a side note, using a StringBuilder could give you a slight boost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments strings are immutable and each conatenation creates new string the more strings is present in memory, the slower processing is. 
So the string processing should be avoided completely.

```
 For x As Integer = 0 To dtRows
        'set row values'
        For y As Integer = 0 To dtColumns
            WriteIntoFile(fileName,dt(x)(y))
            If (y <> dtColumns) Then
                WriteIntoFile(fileName,";")
            Else
                WriteIntoFile(fileName, vbCrLf)
            End If
        Next

        If (x Mod 300 = 0 And x <> 0) Then

            WriteIntoFile(fileName,textOnlyColumn)

            ts = Now().Subtract(t1)
            addText(TextLog, "Execution time in " + ts.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + " msec.")
            t1 = Now()

            Application.DoEvents()
        End If
    Next
```

**Note**

Just for studying purposes you can try to include (to the `mod 300` branch)

```
GC.Collect
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers
```

and look how it influences performance.